# Are there any ways to bind the enter key to a Tkinter.Toplevel() window in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tk window opening another. This secondary window is used as my input for a program. I would like to read the results each time the cartage return key is pressed. I read somewhere that the method I am trying to use (below) only works for root .Tk() windows.

```
input_window.bind('<Return>',lambda: function_to_save_data (args) )
```

Is there a way to get around this, or an alternative way to do such a thing?
(I have tried this, and it fails to work, and does not bug out, thus the question above)

Comment: Show more code - I made simple test and I can use `Enter` on Toplevel window - but not `Enter` from numeric keyboard (this `Enter` probably has different keycode and need different argument in `bind()`).

Comment: @furas My current code is `:    
    edd = tk.Tk()
    edd.title("Title ")
    edd.geometry("1279x800+0+0")    edd.bind('<Enter>',kill ) ` where kill is a function that closes down the system  Edit:(turns out my code doesn't work on a normal tk window either)

Comment: Add code to question - it will be more readable. And where do you have `Toplevel` window with binded `<Return>` ?

Comment: BTW: `<Enter>` means mouse entered on widget - not key `Enter` on keyboard. See in Tkinterbook: [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: BTW: did you made any test with `Toplevel` and `<Return>` or you only read about some problem ?

Comment: I tested with both and then proceeded to try everything else, thus the 'enter' and no longer `toplevel`. This is my code at the moment (I have commented out all the buttons and isolated the module so it runs independently for debugging purposes). No luck on other keys such as `<Up>` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind works for any window, there are no special cases.

The problem you are experiencing is likely due to the fact that top level windows may not get keyboard focus. When you press a key, it is the window with focus that processes the event.

Comment: Manually focusing on one of the background frames of the uppermost window solved the problem.